# Problems retrieving results with Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I am having trouble retrieving a value using a foreign key in Laravel. I have a column in my bulletins table, "creator_id", that references "id" on my users table. I haven't had a problem with similar attempts to retrieve data, but this just won't seem to work. dd($creator) returns a massive object, which does have the data I'm looking for, but I can't access it with creator()->name like the docs say I should. Still new to laravel, but here is what I have currently.

Function in controller:

```
    public function showBulletin()
    {
       $creator = Bulletin::find(1)->creator();
       dd($creator);
       $posts = Bulletin::all();
       return View::make('bulletin')->with(array('posts'=>$posts,'creator'=>$creator));
    }
```

Bulletin Model:

```
<?php

class Bulletin extends Eloquent {

public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');// TODO create comments table
}

public function type()
{
    //if 1 then, etc
}
}
```

User model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

public function tags()
{   
    //TO REMOVE RECORD
    //Tag::find(1)->tags()->detach();

    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag'); 
}

public function createUser()
{
    $password = Hash::make('secret');
}

public function bulletin()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Bulletin','creator_id');
}

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}

}
```

and the function from my migration that I used to create the table:

```
    Schema::create('bulletins',function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('creator_id')->unsigned()->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('comments_id')->unsigned();// todo add foreign key constraint later when comments table is made
        $table->integer('type')->unsigned();
        $table->mediumText('title');
        $table->longText('content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `get` method:

```
$creator = Bulletin::find(1)->creator()->get();
// or simply
$creator = Bulletin::find(1)->creator;
```

Comment: Oh... wow, simple solution. Thank you, at least I have that figured out now. Now that it returns the right result, what could I put in "find()" to use it in a foreach in my view?

Comment: You welcome. Just remember with `->creator()` you access to the relation, so you can chain more conditions (e.g., `->creator()->lists('id')` )

Comment: Is there a way to maybe append that name to the $posts object in my controller so I can just call to it as $post->name in my foreach?

Comment: Of course yes, in your `foreach` you can do `$post->creator->name` (in fact, you don't need `$creator`). However, eager load your relation to avoid `count($posts)` queries, briefly : `$posts = Bulletin::with('creator')->get();` ( please visit http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading for more information)